# How to request permission for MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in Android 12?

Tags: android, filesystems, android-permissions

Before you say "Google will deny this app access to the Play Store for invoking this permission" or "This permission is dangerous" please note that this is an app for personal use and will never see the Play Store.
I am designing an app that requires access to the main directory so a arbitrary file can be dropped which is then retrieved over a USB connection at a later time.

In Manifest.xml, I have added the following lines:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

But still am a bit confused on how to actually let the user select the proper permission so I can actually access the main directory. Putting the following line in MainActivity.java prompts an unexpected token along with numerous syntax issues.

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
        if (Environment.isExternalStorageManager()){
         }else{
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", this.getPackageName(), null);
            intent.setData(uri);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
```

What exactly am I doing wrong? Is this code block supposed to be inside an onClickListener in a fragment or in another file?

Comment: Do not request that permission to begin with. And only launch the intent if you are not the external storage manager.

Comment: ???? It was just an answer to your question `What exactly am I doing wrong?`. Well i told you.